# Div Tag Heights and scroll bars

Tags: css, layout

I have a layout using DIV tags and I have having a hard time controlling the fill of the div tags as well as unnecessary scroll bars.  When the content in the "rightside" div tag doesn't fill the screen there is still a scroll bar on the page.  How do I cut the tags so they don't fill past the first screen if not needed.

A second issue that I have is when there is enough content in the "rightside" div tag to create the need for a scroll bar, the background of the "sidebar" div tag does not extent to match the bottom of the "rightside"

I have played around with so many of the tag, I have no clue where to go from here.   Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is my CSS Code:

```
.content_container {
border:2px solid red;
overflow: auto;
height:100%;
}

#sidebar {
background:#a4c2c2;
width:231px;
font:12px georgia;
color: #336666;
line-height:18px;
float:left;
position: absolute;
overflow:hidden;
z-index:-1;   
height:100%;
min-height:auto;
}
#sidebar div {
height:2000px;
}
#rightside {
float: left;
 width: 500px;
height:100%;
margin-left:231px;
padding: 10px 0px 0px 25px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/03hcm6ta/

EDIT-

I solved my issue, well almost, with a table. However there is a weird border issue happening and I can't seem to solve it.  The side bar and rightside div tags dont seem to completely cover the content_container div. Any suggestions?

http://jsfiddle.net/eh92awh0/

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I've understood your issue... You had a couple of stray /div tags plus you'd opened paragraphs with P and closed with /p and some duplicated classes in your CSS :)

EDIT - Updated fiddle; http://jsfiddle.net/richardblyth/L9afr65f/

The key is setting all relevant elements to

```
height: 100%;
position: relative;
```

And on your container

```
overflow: hidden;
```

See my fiddle :)

Comment: That solved the side bar extension issue, but I still have a scroll bar even if one is not needed.

Comment: So another issue,  one page has about 5 pages worth of content but you can only scroll down about 4 lines and it gets cut off

Comment: Do you have a height value (e.g. 2000px) somewhere, coupled with overflow:scroll ? Could you post an updated fiddle and I'll take a look :)

Comment: Okay, so i have taken a break from this issue and I feel like i am starting over.  My current issue is when there is not enough content for a whole screen the div tags do not expand to fill the first screen.  If one side gets longer than the other the both fill to the same size.  Any help on the initial page load?  http://jsfiddle.net/eh92awh0/2/